# How to define a CustomID of TextInputBuilder

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I want to call **titlem** which is in this file:
File #**1**

```
const { ButtonInteraction, Client } = require("discord.js");

module.exports = {
    id: "title",
    /**
     * 
     * @param {ButtonInteraction} interaction 
     * @param {Client} client 
     */
    async execute(interaction, client) {
        const mtitle = new ModalBuilder()
        .setCustomId('mtitle')
        .setTitle('Set a title.')
        .setComponents(
          new ActionRowBuilder().setComponents(
              new TextInputBuilder()
              .setLabel('Title')
              .setCustomId('titlem')
              .setStyle(TextInputStyle.Short)
          ),
        )
                interaction.showModal(mtitle)
    }
}
```

To This File:
**File 2**

```
const { ButtonInteraction, Client, EmbedBuilder } = require("discord.js");

module.exports = {
    id: "send",
    /**
     * 
     * @param {ButtonInteraction} interaction 
     * @param {client} client 
     */
    async execute(interaction, client) {
        interaction.reply({embeds: [new EmbedBuilder().setDescription()]})

    }
}
```

So how do i define **.setCustomId('titlem')** in File **2**? Please help, thank you so much :D.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a `messageComponentCollector` in "File 1" and listen to interactions through it instead of making another file.

```js
const filter = i => i.customId === 'titlem' && i.user.id === interaction.user.id;

const collector = interaction.channel.createMessageComponentCollector({ filter, time: 15000 });

collector.on('collect', async i => {
    await i.reply({ content: 'A button was clicked!', ephemeral: true });
});

collector.on('end', collected => console.log('No Interactions Collected.'));
```

[More info](https://discordjs.guide/interactions/buttons.html#updating-the-button-message)

Comment: I want the id to go to file #2 since I have more files like File #1 that I want the id's of

Comment: Then use client `interactionCreate` event.